# Parent grid is narrower than subgrid free-jqgrid 4.8.0

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Last time I changed version of jqGrid (4.6.0 to free-jqgrid 4.8.0) and jQuery (1.7.2 to 2.1.3) in my application. 
In my parent grid I have 2 visible columns that has 100 px width each, and in subgrid there are 5 visible columns that has 200 px width each. In previous version, subgrid was on the top so I could see all the columns from subgrid without resizing any column.
 
After change to obtain the same result If I want to see all cols from subgrid I need to do workaround and add empty column (what I don't want to do). Is there anything that I can do? 
It could work with bigger second column in the parent grid but I don't want to resize it, and I prefer to leave it with 100 px with.

Definition of grids:

```
function loadFirstGrid() {
        var data = {
            "page": "1",
            "records": "3",
            "rows": [
            { "DataID": "1", "DataDesc": "Test 1", "DataTitle": "Test 1" },
            { "DataID": "2", "DataDesc": "Test 2", "DataTitle": "Test 2" },
            { "DataID": "3", "DataDesc": "Test 3", "DataTitle": "Test 3" }
        ]
        };

        $("#FirstGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: "GET",
            contentType: "text/xml",
            colNames: ['DataID', 'DataDesc', 'DataTitle'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'DataID', index: 'DataID', hidden: true, key: true },
            { name: 'DataDesc', index: 'DataDesc', width: 100 },
            { name: 'DataTitle', index: 'DataTitle', width: 100 }
          ],
            rowNum: 10000,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: data,
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortname: 'DataDesc',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            emtyrecords: "Nothing to display",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: "100%",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            loadonce: true,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            width: 2000,
            caption: 'First Grid',
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: loadSubGrid,
            gridview: false
        });
    }

    function loadSubGrid(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var data = {
            "page": "1",
            "records": "3",
            "rows": [
            { "SubGridID": "1", "FirstCol": "Test 1", "SecondCol": "Test 1", "ThirdCol": "Test 1", "FourthCol": "Test 1", "FifthCol": "Test 1" },
            { "SubGridID": "2", "FirstCol": "Test 2", "SecondCol": "Test 2", "ThirdCol": "Test 1", "FourthCol": "Test 1", "FifthCol": "Test 1" },
            { "SubGridID": "3", "FirstCol": "Test 3", "SecondCol": "Test 3", "ThirdCol": "Test 1", "FourthCol": "Test 1", "FifthCol": "Test 1" }
        ]
        };

        var subgrid_table_id;
        var dataID = $("#FirstGrid").jqGrid('getRowData', row_id).DataID;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_SubGrid";
        $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<div><table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table></div>");
        $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: "GET",
            contentType: "text/xml",
            colNames: ['SubGridID', 'FirstCol', 'SecondCol', 'ThirdCol', 'FourthCol', 'FifthCol'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'SubGridID', index: 'SubGridID', hidden: true, key: true },
                { name: 'FirstCol', index: 'FirstCol', editable: false, width: 200 },
                { name: 'SecondCol', index: 'SecondCol', width: 200 },
                { name: 'ThirdCol', index: 'ThirdCol', width: 200 },
                { name: 'FourthCol', index: 'FourthCol', width: 200 },
                { name: 'FifthCol', index: 'FifthCol', width: 200 },
              ],
            rowNum: 10000,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: data,
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortname: 'FirstCol',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            emtyrecords: "Nothing to display",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: "100%",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            loadonce: true,
            scrollOffset: 0,
            width: 1900,
            caption: 'SubGrid',
            gridview: false
        });
    }
```

**Edit:**
Demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mlodey/2tkkqbeq/3/)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many changes in the CSS structure of free jqGrid 4.8 comparing with jqGrid 4.7. So I would recommend to solve your problem in another way. You can add new last column at the end on the parent grid. The column can have empty header. As the result the parent grid will looks exactly line before, but now you will don't have the described problem.

I modified your demo to the following http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2tkkqbeq/4/. I removed many unneeded settings like `class='scroll'`, `datatype: "xml"` (which can't be used *together* with `datatype: "jsonstring"`). I removed *all `index` properties* from `colModel`. I removed some other properties which are default now.

It's important to remove `gridview: false` property which makes the grid just working slowly and have no other advantages. I recommend you to use `datatype: "local"` with `data: data.rows` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: data`. The main advantage of the changes: the input data will by sorted by jqGrid corresponds to `sortname` option which you use.

I would recommend you to use `autowidth: true` in subgrid.

The last, but very important change which I made in your demo, is including the option `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_"` in the subgrid. Without the usage of the option you will have **id duplicates** on the page because both main grid and subgrid will have the same `id` values (1, 2, 3).

Comment: Thanks Oleg for help. I wanted not to use additional column but if it's necessary it's not big change.
This view has `datatype: "xml"` in my application, but I changed that for the demo. 
I added `gridview: false` because in my application when the flag is set to `true` I get an error `JavaScript runtime error: Invalid target element for this operation.` at line: `self.firstElementChild.innerHTML += rowData.join(''); // append to innerHTML of tbody which contains the first row (.jqgfirstrow)`

Comment: @user2595836: You are welcome! The HTML markup which you used before was relative exotic, because the subgrid is *child* of the row of the main grid (the table), but the table was not large enough. Only the width of the body div over the grid was large enough. So creating of an additional column is the most clean pragmatic solution, which holds your existing layout. Such solution will works with jqGrid 4.6 too.

Comment: @user2595836. I know problems with `self.firstElementChild.innerHTML` **only in IE in versions less then 10**. **If you would get the latest sources of free jqGrid from [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), then you should not have the problem.** You can load the latest version of free jqGrid directly from github like described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit), but you should use the way only in demos and not in the final solutions.

Comment: I downloaded new version but problem still exists. I tried to find what the problem is and I replaced line `self.firstElementChild.innerHTML += rowData.join('');` with `$(self.firstElementChild).replaceWith('<tbody>' + self.firstElementChild.innerHTML + rowData.join('') + '</tbody>');`
I tested that on IE9 and it works. It's not deeply tested so I don't know if something is not broken, but there is no longer the error with changing the innerHTML for the object. Thanks once again for help. Tommorow I'll try to do some more tests.

Comment: @user2595836: Could you provide the demo which can be used to reproduces the problem with `self.firstElementChild.innerHTML`?

Comment: Yes, sure it's also in the demo that You sent in this post: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/2tkkqbeq/4/ Please, could You open it in Internet Explorer with IE9 mode? It's because in IE9 there is a bug that You cannot change the innerHTML in some of elements like table, tbody etc.

Comment: @user2595836: the demo uses **not the latest code from github**. It uses version 4.8. To use the latest code one can use  paths like `//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)). Try the demo  http://jsfiddle.net/2tkkqbeq/6/

Comment: Sorry I thought I got the latest code. I checked it and there is no problem with "gridview". But there is another problem, I've got grid like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mlodey/97jL4265/10/ The only difference is that in my app I'm using `datatype: "xml"` (three commented lines in the first grid). When data is loaded there is visible only one column - it should be 'Team_Desc', but it's filled with IDs not with Team Descriptions. When I commented lines: `subGrid and subGridRowExpanded` the data was displayed correctly.

Comment: @user2595836: Sorry, but I don't understand what problem you have. If I open the demo I see grid with the data from `'Team_Desc'` column: `Test 1`, `Test 2`, `Test 3`. I see ids only if I use Developer Tools to examine HTML.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on jsfiddle. It is in my application when I'm getting the data as xml from my WebService. In every grid that has `subGrid: true`. Column with IDs is visible and second column has `display: none` attribute. Captions for every columns are correct

Comment: @user2595836: Sorry, but I can analyse the problem only if I have the demo which reproduces it. By the way if you have ASMX web service than it should convert the results automatically to JSON if the request have `Accept: application/json` in HTTP header. So you can just try to change `datatype: "xml"` to `datatype: "json"` and examine the server response using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/firefox. I suppose that you will see JSON data in the server response. Processing of JSON data is much better in JavaScript as processing of XML data.

Comment: For now I have too many views that are using `datatype: "xml"` and converting it to `datatype: "json"` would be painfull. That's why it's important for me to stay with "xml" in that moment. I created simple project where I reproduced the problem. Please, could you check it? It's available here: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/0b160816

Comment: @user2595836: Thank you for the test case. It was the bug. Pleas retry with the latest sources from GitHub. If you use URLs like `...//rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/...` then you could just press F5 in web browser.

Comment: @user2595836: By the way the usage of manual serialization to XML is not needed if you use .NET 3.5 or higher. The code of `GetFirstGridXML` method could looks very simple: `[WebMethod][ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]  public object GetFirstGridXML() { return new [] { new {CCID = 1, CCIDDesc = "Test1", CCTitle = "Test1"}, new {CCID = 2, CCIDDesc = "Test2", CCTitle = "Test2"}, new {CCID = 3, CCIDDesc = "Test3", CCTitle = "Test3"} };}`. So it can just return array of items.

Comment: @user2595836: The jqGrid code should use `datatype: "json", ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }, jsonReader: { root: "d" }, loadonce: true`. In the way the code of both client and the server will be simple any processing will be more quickly. The usage of `loadonce: true` allows to use **local** sorting or filtering (just include call of `filterToolbar`) or searching (call `navGrid` for example).

Comment: Thank you for fixing it and tips, now it works. For now the application is using .NET 2.0 but soon it will be converted to 4.5 so I'll remeber that. Also I'll try to convert it to use `datatype: "json"` not `datatype: "xml"`. Once again big thanks - you are doing great job!